# Move tableview down to show hidden textfield

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a view controller that I've dropped a tableview into. I've also added a UITextField behind the tableview. When I click the search button, I would like the tableview to shift down (showing the textfield). I though I had this figured out by using the following:

```
self.tableView.frame.origin.y += 50
```

This works, but as soon as I click on the textfield, it vanishes. I've also included a screenshot that I think will help you understand what i'm trying to achieve.Trying to do this in Swift. Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Seems odd that you're doing it this way instead of a `UISearchBar`. Anyways, try pinning the vertical spacing between the `UITableView` and the nav bar or even the `UITextField`. Create an `IBOutlet` for the constraint and resize that accordingly. Constraints seem to work more effectively (at least for me) than moving origins.

Comment: I agree with Caleb that you will save yourself a lot of time and effort by using a `UISearchBar`.

Comment: I started off thinking I would use a UISearchBar, but I may need to have 2 search fields. I couldn't find a way to do that. Also, I'm not trying to search the existing rows, but return new ones based on the text entered. Isn't the UISearchBar generally for searching through the returned rows? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answers on here were helpful if I went down the UISearchBar path, I really needed to show a custom search field. I was able to achieve that by doing the following:

1. Use AutoLayout
2. Create an IBOutlet for my vertical constraint
3. Using the following code: `tableViewConstraint.constant += 65`

Thanks to everyone who tried to help out!

Answer (score 1):

You can set your UITextField to be the UITableView's headerView, shown as below:

```
// set the tableHeaderView to be your UITextField
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = YOUR_TEXTFIELD
// set the offset so that the textField will be initially hidden
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, YOUR_TEXTFIELD.frame.size.height)
// then in the IBAction of your search button, set the offset to be (0,0)
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
```

Actually you don't need to put a button there. A scrolling down of the UITableView will show the headerView(aka the UITextField) at the top.

BTW, a UISearchBar is better choice than a UITextField for your case.

**UPDATE:**

Hope you have read my answer above. I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I would just update my answer.

Based on your comment (maybe you should add that to your question detail, btw):

- UISearchBar IS generally for searching existing rows, but it CAN do other things. Anyway, the tableView's data is in your control. You can determine how to update rows in the delegate method:
  `- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController`
- As for multiple searching fields, there are two ways I could come up with:

  1. Support the spaces between keywords in the UISearchBar so that user can search for the combination of several keywords. Try this:

  `// strip out all the leading and trailing spaces`
  `NSString *strippedString = [YOUR_SEARCHBAR_TEXT stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];`

  `// break up the search terms (separated by spaces)
  NSArray *searchItems = nil;
  if (strippedString.length > 0) {
      searchItems = [strippedString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
  }`

  2. Use the scope buttons of UISearchBar if needed.